# Is there a reason why my Python code works fine when run line by line in interpreter, but not when executing script via terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlwings

So I'm just trying to open up an Excel spreadsheet and activate a macro using xlwings

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book(r'/Users/jappleseed/Desktop/test.xlsm⁩')
```

When input into the interpreter line by line, it works 100% fine. Excel spreadsheet opens up, and I can then input code that activates the macro. But when the same code is in a script and run through terminal with `python scriptName.py`, Excel opens up a blank spreadsheet and I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/jappleseed/Desktop/timesheetAutofill.py", line 3, in 
wb = xw.Book(r'/Users/jappleseed/Desktop/test.xlsm⁩')
File "/Users/jappleseed/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlwings/main.py", line 524, in **init**
add_to_mru, local, corrupt_load).impl
File "/Users/jappleseed/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlwings/main.py", line 2939, in open
raise FileNotFoundError("No such file: '%s'" % fullname)
FileNotFoundError: No such file: '/users/jappleseed/desktop/test.xlsm⁩'

If I run `os.path.exists` in the script to the location of the file, I get back True.

I also checked `sys.executable` in the interpreter and from the script, and get the same location.

Any ideas?

Comment: The path in the traceback is not the same as the one you're using in the interpreter though.`FileNotFoundError: No such file: '/users/jappleseed/desktop/test.xlsm⁩'`. all lowercase?

Comment: I've tried all lowercase, still nothing. I've copied and pasted the exact same file path from the interpreter when it works, to the script, but still no luck. Same error message every time :(

Comment: This may be an encoding issue.  When I copy/paste the code from the post, I see there are a few invisible non-ascii bytes between `.xlsm` and the closing `'`.  The hex values are e2 81 a9.  This is a unicode sequence.  Your terminal may be using a different encoding than your script uses, which might explain the difference.  Try deleting and re-typing everything after `/test` to the end of the line and see if it helps.

Comment: Yep that was it @TomKarzes! Thanks so much. Can I ask how you found that out? What did you copy the text into? Thanks again!

Comment: @calvywd Hah, yeah it was pretty hidden wasn't it?  I wanted to look at the string in Python, so I just highlighted the code in my browser, selected "copy", then pasted it into my Python interpreter.  It gave an error, so I put it in a file and then did a hex dump to see what was there.

Comment: @calvywd paths are case sensitive. You shouldn't try different character cases for that.

Comment: @DevonHorizon Windows file names are case-insensitive.  The error message probably converted it to lowercase when reporting it.  I suspect OP just pasted the error text exactly as it was displayed.

Comment: The bytes with hex values `e2 81 a9`, in UTF-8 encoding, represent the character `'\u2069'` (as Python represents it in a `str`), named [POP DIRECTIONAL ISOLATE](http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/2069.html) in the Unicode name database. This is a control code used as part of the [system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_text) that controls whether text is rendered left-to-right or right-to-left (as some written languages expect).

Comment: I never knew Windows paths were case-insensitive, good to know.. Still, its better habit to use exact file names for file anywhere even if windows lets you get away with all lowercase. One day the code will move to linux and then it breaks. Especially because the path here could possibly exist in linux too.